# Insert consecutive numbers into a table

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id     name     age
       John     23
       Mary     22
       Mike     25
       etc      etc
```

I would like to generate consecutive number into `id` column for every record. Could anyone help me?

Sorry if I asked the same question as asked before.

Comment: So Set id column as identity

Comment: It worked with the first answer. But, i have one more question: can I use a clause to start with a specific answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to add a sequential number:

```
SELECT
    id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
    name,
    age
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to update table through `CTE`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(50) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 3, 'a' ),
        ( 5, 'b' ),
        ( 10, 'c' )


SELECT  * FROM    @t;

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) AS RN
               FROM     @t
             )
    UPDATE  cte
    SET     ID = RN

SELECT  * FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
ID  Name
3   a
5   b
10  c

ID  Name
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Instead of

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) AS RN
```

you can do

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Name ) AS RN
```

in order to increment values by ordering in `Name` column.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table then add identity and it will generate value

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   Add id Int Identity(1, 1)
```

Comment: what you  are saying ?Add identity instead .

Comment: Primary key does NOT generate a value. perhaps you mean identity.

Comment: I would like to update a table with sequential number. In this case, what's the code for updating column id with sequential number?

Comment: @CodriAfrasinei,  i updated my answer.. execute that and it will generate a sequential id number